# How to properly use RxJS 5 in a typescript project using webpack 3?

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, webstorm, rxjs5

I am trying to run a simple typescript project using webpack 3 and rxjs5 but I am getting an error.

app.ts :

```
 import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

    import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';

        const myObservable: any = Observable.of(1, 2, 3)
            .subscribe(
                (value: any) => console.log(value),
                (err: any) => console.log(err),
                () => console.log("Streaming is over")
        );
```

index.html :

```
   <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport"
              content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Webpack 3 with Typescript</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <h1>Let's learn Webpack 3</h1>

    <script src="dist/bundle.js"></script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

package.json :

```
{
  "name": "ObservablesProject2",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack-dev-server",
    "build:prod": "webpack -p"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "ts-loader": "^3.0.2",
    "tslint": "^5.7.0",
    "tslint-loader": "^3.5.3",
    "typescript": "^2.5.3",
    "webpack": "^3.7.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.9.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "rxjs": "^5.4.3"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Basic Options */
    "target": "es5",                          /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "commonjs",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'none', commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', or 'ESNext'. */
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],                             /* Specify library files to be included in the compilation:  */
    "allowJs": true,                       /* Allow javascript files to be compiled. */
    // "checkJs": true,                       /* Report errors in .js files. */
    // "jsx": "preserve",                     /* Specify JSX code generation: 'preserve', 'react-native', or 'react'. */
    // "declaration": true,                   /* Generates corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    "sourceMap": true,                     /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */
    // "outFile": "./",                       /* Concatenate and emit output to single file. */
    // "outDir": "./",                        /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */
    // "rootDir": "./",                       /* Specify the root directory of input files. Use to control the output directory structure with --outDir. */
    // "removeComments": true,                /* Do not emit comments to output. */
    // "noEmit": true,                        /* Do not emit outputs. */
    // "importHelpers": true,                 /* Import emit helpers from 'tslib'. */
    // "downlevelIteration": true,            /* Provide full support for iterables in 'for-of', spread, and destructuring when targeting 'ES5' or 'ES3'. */
    // "isolatedModules": true,               /* Transpile each file as a separate module (similar to 'ts.transpileModule'). */

    /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
    "strict": true,                            /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    "noImplicitAny": true,                 /* Raise error on expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */
    "strictNullChecks": true             /* Enable strict null checks. */
    // "noImplicitThis": true,                /* Raise error on 'this' expressions with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "alwaysStrict": true,                  /* Parse in strict mode and emit "use strict" for each source file. */

    /* Additional Checks */
    // "noUnusedLocals": true,                /* Report errors on unused locals. */
    // "noUnusedParameters": true,            /* Report errors on unused parameters. */
    // "noImplicitReturns": true,             /* Report error when not all code paths in function return a value. */
    // "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,    /* Report errors for fallthrough cases in switch statement. */

    /* Module Resolution Options */
    // "moduleResolution": "node",            /* Specify module resolution strategy: 'node' (Node.js) or 'classic' (TypeScript pre-1.6). */
    // "baseUrl": "./",                       /* Base directory to resolve non-absolute module names. */
    // "paths": {},                           /* A series of entries which re-map imports to lookup locations relative to the 'baseUrl'. */
    // "rootDirs": [],                        /* List of root folders whose combined content represents the structure of the project at runtime. */
    // "typeRoots": [],                       /* List of folders to include type definitions from. */
    // "types": [],                           /* Type declaration files to be included in compilation. */
    // "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,  /* Allow default imports from modules with no default export. This does not affect code emit, just typechecking. */
    // "preserveSymlinks": true,              /* Do not resolve the real path of symlinks. */

    /* Source Map Options */
    // "sourceRoot": "./",                    /* Specify the location where debugger should locate TypeScript files instead of source locations. */
    // "mapRoot": "./",                       /* Specify the location where debugger should locate map files instead of generated locations. */
    // "inlineSourceMap": true,               /* Emit a single file with source maps instead of having a separate file. */
    // "inlineSources": true,                 /* Emit the source alongside the sourcemaps within a single file; requires '--inlineSourceMap' or '--sourceMap' to be set. */

    /* Experimental Options */
    // "experimentalDecorators": true,        /* Enables experimental support for ES7 decorators. */
    // "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,         /* Enables experimental support for emitting type metadata for decorators. */
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

webpack.config.js :

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {

    entry: './src/js/app.ts',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/dist'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                enforce: 'pre',
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                loader: 'tslint-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                options: {
                    failOnHint: true,
                    configuration: require('./tslint.json')
                }
            },

            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js"]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            // ...
        })
    ]

};
```

The error I am getting when I try to compile the above code is the following:

```
ERROR in ./src/js/app.ts
[tsl] ERROR in /Users/administrator/WebstormProjects/ObservablesProject2/src/js/app.ts(1,28)
      TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'rxjs/Observable'. '/Users/administrator/WebstormProjects/ObservablesProject2/node_modules/rxjs/Observable.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm install @types/rxjs/Observable` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'rxjs/Observable';`
```

Comment: Try using `(value: number) => console.log(value)`. Notice the `: number` type specificator.

Comment: @IgorSoloydenko I believe that this is a configuration error.Syntactically my code is ok.You can use any for representing any type, number including.

Comment: Got it. I guess you're right. What you can do is temporary disable this thing: `"noImplicitAny": true`. Make it `false` to forgive you, while you're experimenting. If after using `"noImplicitAny": false` code works, you know what to look for, but I'm not sure _where_ -- in your code or in RxJs... Give it a shot.

Comment: @IgorSoloydenkoI I have already tried that but I must repeat that this is a configuration error.

Comment: Tsconfig is a part of your configuration too

Comment: @IgorSoloydenko I set noImplicitAny to false and removed the UglifyJs plugin and it worked but I want to use noImplicitAny: true for my coding so I wonder why the exclude "node_modules" is not working!

Comment: Sorry I went to bed yesterday and forgot to turn on my laptop while dreaming :) glad you found a solution

Answer (score -1):

Using awesome-typescript-loader instead of ts-loader did the trick for me.
Now I can use noImplicitAny: true for my own coding and node_modules folder is excluded from the compilation process.